# Does $f(x)=x \ln (x)$ have a vertical tangent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, tangent-line

Does $f(x)=x \ln (x)$ have a vertical tangent

We have domain of $f(x)$ as $(0 ,\: \: \infty)$

Now

$$f'(x)=1+\ln x$$

we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) =-\infty$$

Can we say $f$ has vertical tangent at origin?

Comment: We can only say the function, *continued at* $0$ by $f(0)=0$, has a vertical tangent at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, for there is no point there on the graph for which you could build such a tangent line ($x=0$ is outside the domain, as you've noted).  The function $f(x) =x^{2/3}$ exhibits the behavior you are asking about.

Comment: Ya vertical asymptote for $f'(x)$ right?

Comment: Vertical asymptote for $f'(x)$, but not $f(x)$ (necessarily), correct.

Comment: So $x=a$ is Vertical tangent only when $x=a$ is in domain. Is that right?

Comment: For me, yes, assuming the derivative goes to $+\infty$ on both sides (or $-\infty$ on both).  You need the point to build the line.  I imagine there could be other conventions which disagree (and no one is "wrong").  It's a little delicate since vertical lines aren't functions so there could be other interpretations depending on how "bad" the function is at $x=a$.

Comment: As a nit, my read of the definition of a vertical asymptote (per the Wikipedia page) would be that f(x) (not just f'(x)) has one at zero.

Comment: I don't agree: usually, we say the graph of $f$ has $(0,0)$ as a *limit point*, which allows for continuing the function at $x=0$.

Comment: @Bernard  I figured that point would come up.  To me, that would be extending $f$ to a new function, which then would have that (one-sided) vertical tangent.

Comment: Perhaps the real answer for OP is that it's a matter of taste and convention:  check your text and/or instructor.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not defined at $0$, so it cannot have a tangent there. However, if you *extend* it by declaring
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\ln\lvert x\lvert & x\ne0 \\[4px]
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
then the function is continuous at $0$ and differentiable for $x\ne0$; since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}(\ln|x|+1)=-\infty
$$
you can indeed conclude that the function has vertical tangent at $0$.

<sub>It's not the only way to extend the function; the important thing is that the value at $x=0$ is $0$, in order to make it continuous. Choosing an odd function doesn't seem a bad idea.</sub>